# Cisio interface naming rule

Tags: router, interface

I'm very new to networking. I noticed in GNS3 lab environment, if I want to configure IP address for an interface of a router, I can use `int f0/0` or `int fastEthernet 0/0`. What's the naming rule here? I can't find related information in the document.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All Cisco commands can be abbreviated. You have to type enough of the command so that it is unambiguous. You can type

`interface`

`interf`

or just

`int`

It's the same for interface names:

`f0/0` is the same as `fa0/0` or `fastethernet0\0`

Answer (score 1):

- `fastEthernet` or simply `f` is a 10/100 Mbit/s Ethernet interface, `g` 10/100/1000 Mbit/s, and so on
- the `0/0` specifies the module number and the port number within the module
- with stacked/multi-chassis switches, the first number in `0/0/0` denotes the chassis